# Discord.py How can get attachment in message.content

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, attachment

I'm trying to make a bot. It's an archive bot. If some message getting some emoji and some amount, it's moving message to a specific channel that user chooses. I have a problem: it's working well but it's not getting attachment in message.content. Just getting strings, not attachment. How can I fix this problem?

Here is my code:

```
@Bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    user = Bot.get_user(payload.user_id)
    guild = Bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    channel =
guild.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)

#some files is opening in these lines...


    if #some check points..
            else:
              await guild.get_channel(to_list[sıra]).send("Written by {} :\n\n {}".format(message.author.mention,message.content))

              await guild.get_channel(from_list[sıra]).send("{} your message move to this channel --> {}".format(message.author.mention,Bot.get_channel(to_list[sıra]).mention))
              await message.add_reaction("✔️")
```

How can i get attachment in message.content in **on_raw_reaction_add** function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `files` in [`send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=send#discord.abc.Messageable.send) method. Example:

```py
await channel.send(
    message.content, files=[await f.to_file() for f in message.attachments]
)
```

In your case it will probably look like that:

```py
await guild.get_channel(to_list[sıra]).send(
    "Written by {} :\n\n {}".format(message.author.mention, message.content),
    files=[await f.to_file() for f in message.attachments],
)
```

Reference:

- [discord.Message.attachments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=attachments#discord.Message.attachments)
- [discord.Attachment.to_file](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=to_file#discord.Attachment.to_file)
- [List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand. Can you put this on my code? for your example.

Comment: But i'm using payload instead of ctx. is it going to be "payload.message.attachments" ?

Comment: No, you defined `message` in this `message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)` it will just be `message.attachments` (If I understand your point)